# how can I browse localStorage on the device

Tags: android, local-storage, ionic-framework

I am building an application for android device using the Ionic framework. I want to store my data using localStorage. Now, I understand what it is but I can't find it anywhere on the device. I want to browse it to check if everything is saved as I want to.

I found many different tools to browse localStorage when I create app and run it under my device (real phone not emulator) is there a way to browse data store in localStorage ?

Answer (score 11):

Using remote debugging (for Chrome to Android or Safari to iOS) you can easily browser LocalStorage on the device (or emulator). This article documents how to do it with Chrome (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) and this one covers Safari (http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/).